# Material design multi select dropdown add value on button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, multi-select, materialize

So I am fairly new at using Material design and I am facing a problem here, I want to check the boxes or select multiple options from my multi-select dropdown when I press a button, like

If I press an edit button it should check the boxes according to the data that is being fetched from a database, and data is being received in an array.

like data with value Delhi, Gujarat etc should be selected when I press the edit button.

[when I press the edit button I receive this is data that I have console logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRgdp.jpg)

[Here is how I want for it to look before and after I press the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egBk4.jpg)

What currently I am doing is this:

```
 $('#edit').on('click', function(){
          $('[name="multiselect"]').val(data);
          $('[name="multiselect"]').material_select();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem with the code,

The problem was that the data that was being fetched contained spaces like:
["A","*space*B","*space*C","*space*D"]

so my function was comparing
*space*B with B

That is why I was only getting the first value.

so I used a trim function

and now my code looks like

```
$('#edit').on('click', function(){
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                selectArr[i] = data[i].trim();
          $('[name="multiselect"]').val(data);
          $('[name="multiselect"]').material_select();
});
```